# styling affected by parent page css

Tags: css, iframe

I'm hosting a webpage and wrapping my content (the body) with a 3rd party websites header/footer html and their styling. I have my own styling associated with the content in the body of the page but some of the 3rd party websites styling is affecting my content.  Is there something I can wrap my HTML code with to block the styling from the 3rd party?

Comment: That doesn't sound right. Do you mean the parent's styling is affecting the frame itself? Or is affecting content embedded inside the frame?

Comment: What makes you think the third-party stylesheets are affecting your site? Have you confirmed this with Firebug?

Answer (score 1):

You must be mistaken. That can't happen.

You might be including the same style sheets in both the parent page and the iframe content page.

Comment: I actually think I described this incorrectly.  I'm hosting a page and wrapping my content with a 3rd parties header/footer html and styling.  Ultimately their styling is affecting my content in the body of the page.

Comment: Ok, what you do in this scenario is click the "edit" button right below the text of your question and re-write the question with ALL the relevant details.

Answer (score 0):

Add `!important` to the end of your css to ensure that no other css over rides it

ex:

```
#Something
{
    color: White !important;
}
```

Comment: It's not a good practice to use !important, as it can cause other clashes with your own styles down the line. I would recommend using more precise selectors instead. For example: `#site-name div.main a.btn`